# Rubocop implementing local rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I am part of a large organisation, we use CI and CD. As part of our drive to improve our ruby codebase we would like to enforce local rules than the wider team are not using.

We work with 1 codebase shared between 15 teams (over 120 devs) and the rubocop rules implemented at the moment are fairly minimal. We would like to have our team comply with more rules and run this as a test within our team only, before making a decision to roll it out company wide.

We have a `.rubocop.yml` which looks like this:

```
inherit_from:
  - .rubocop/enforced_rules.yml
  - .rubocop/optional_rules.yml
  - .rubocop/disabled_rules.yml
```

We would like to have a local say `.team_a_only_rules.yml` that we can use in our team this file will override the 3 files above.

Is there a way to do this and enforce it before committing any code to the remote?

Also we don't want to commit this `.team_a_only_rules.yml` which I guess we could add it to the `.gitignore` file but the question would be how to enforce the local rules that override all other company wide rules?

Comment: i'm not sure I'm following the need for this.  Will the "local" codebase be shared with the large organization or just the local team?  If not, than why not just have specific rules set at the project/repo level?  But if so, than doesn't not all using the same style guide break the purpose of even having a style guide (i.e. consistency) ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes we do have 1 code base shared by 15 teams, however at the moment the rules implemented company wide are minimal, we would like to build on this, have more stringent rules, try this approach in our team and the roll it out to the rest of the teams.

Comment: You could try setting up a bin/shell script to wrap a command up that uses the extra config file. `bin/rc` for example, could call the alternate config file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass a file to rubocop to use for your rules like this

```
rubocop -c team_a_only_rules.yml
```

But the problem will be with CI because I don't know how you would tell CI when to use which rules.

Comment: I don't see the yml being parsed correctly here by rubocop, so it might require an interim conversion step which should be easy on CI. I tried it with `Style/NumericLiterals` and the false/true (no conditional) and it always interpreted the result as true (enabled)

Comment: Will try this approach and vote the answer if successful.

Comment: I couldn't get the environment variables to work inside the `.rubocop.yml` so I removed that part from my answer.  There is probably a way to get them to work but that would require some hacks or scripts around rubocop itself.